# Why this equation holds?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series

Can someone help me why does this equation holds:

$\sum_{\rho}(1/2 + t -\rho)^{-s}= e^{i\pi s/2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\tau_k+it)^{-s}+e^{-i\pi s/2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\tau_k-it)^{-s}$ for $\rho=1/2 \pm i\tau_k$?

I tried expanding in the Taylor series function $e^{i\pi s/2}$ or as $e^{i\pi s/2}=\cos (\pi s/2) +i \sin(\pi s/2)$, but I get stacked.

Comment: How is the sum $\sum_\rho$ done? Is $\sum_{\rho}  \text{blah}(\rho) = \sum_{k =1}^\infty  \text{blah}(1/2 +i \tau_k) + \sum_{k =1}^\infty \text{blah}(1/2 -i \tau_k)$?

Comment: I get $(t-i\tau)^{-s}=(-i)^{-s}(it+\tau)^{-s}=e^{-i\pi s/2}(\tau+it)^{-s}$ but may/must have messed up an argument.

Comment: Thanks! @ancientmathematician